# Unrecognized or duplicated keyword error using ORCA DFT calculations using avogadro

Tags: computational-chemistry, quantum-chemistry, orca

I'm using Avogadro to generate an input for ORCA, however, when I'm trying to run that input in ORCA it says:

```
"INPUT ERROR UNRECOGNIZED OR DUPLICATED KEYWORD(S) IN SIMPLE INPUT LINE DEF2-SVP/J"
```

(I don't even know what I'm doing help D;)

Input file:

```
# avogadro generated ORCA input file 
# Basic Mode
# 
! BP RI SP def2-SVP def2-SVP/J 

* xyz 0 1
   H        0.77899       -0.00348       -0.13267
   O       -0.14793        0.02998       -0.34219
   H       -0.63110       -0.02651        0.47487
*
```

Comment: Hi Hector. Welcome to our site! Did you check in the ORCA's manual?

Comment: Speculating since I don't have Orca to try this, but it may just be that the auxiliary basis needs to be written `def2/J` rather than `def2-SVP/J`. That's how the examples are written in the [Orca Input Library](https://sites.google.com/site/orcainputlibrary/general-input). Maybe the Avogadro template for Orca is out of date

Comment: @Hektor dks   I have made an answer. Please check if it answers your question. If it does please click on the tick mark next to it. You also get +2 if you do it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to change `def2-SVP def2-SVP/J`  to `def2-SVP def2/J` as per the [ORCA manual](https://sites.google.com/site/orcainputlibrary/general-input), see the heading block input.

I verified that this works on ORCA version : `ORCA 5.0.4, Windows, 64bit`

The input file will look like this:

```
# avogadro generated ORCA input file 
# Basic Mode
# 
! BP RI SP def2-SVP def2/J

* xyz 0 1
   H        0.77899       -0.00348       -0.13267
   O       -0.14793        0.02998       -0.34219
   H       -0.63110       -0.02651        0.47487
*
```